# Blob byte[] property loading slow

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have class containing a byte array property for storing file attachments.

```
public class MyClass
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   ...
   [MaxLength]
   public byte[] Attachment { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that when getting the list for the entities EF loads all attachment from database, which is insane after many files added.

```
public static List<MyClass> GetAllMyClassData()
{
    MyContext.MyEntity.ToList();
}
```

I did the table splitting suggested in many places.

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyClass>()
            .Map(f =>
                {                
                    f.Properties(p => new
                    {
                        p.Id,
                        p.Name
                        ...
                    });
                    f.ToTable("MyClasses");
                })
                .Map(f =>
                {
                    f.Properties(p => new 
                    { 
                        p.Id,
                        p.Attachment
                    });
                    f.ToTable("MyClassAttachments");
                });
```

Now the situation remains the same, like nothing happened.

I checked the database, table splitting was done by EF, however each time I call `GetAllMyClassData()` all attachments are loaded.
How can I force EF to do not load the attachments?

Any idea what did I wrong?

Please note it's a winforms app with MS SQL therefore storing only the path for files are not an options.

Comment: Often times (for this very reason) BLOB data is not stored directly in the database, but instead in a file. Then a reference to the file is stored in the database. This also allows the files to be agnostic of transport medium, as well as allowing browsers/clients to leverage HTTP caching.

Comment: You should split MyClass class in two classes : MyClass and MyClassAttachment